# Loading message

Tags: javascript, load

Searching for a js script, which will show some **message** (something like "Loading, please wait") **until the page loads all images**.

Important - **it mustn't use any js framework** (jquery, mootools, etc), must be an ordinary js script.

Message must disappear when the page is loaded.

Comment: In the future, Mike, don't start questions with "I need..." This is a place to learn, not to get freebies ;)

Comment: my english is not good, maybe you don't understand me. I hope "need" means not "want to get free", but it seems to be a different meaning :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah an old-school question!
This goes back to those days when we used to preload images...

Anyway, here's some code.  The magic is the "complete" property on the document.images collection (Image objects).

```
// setup a timer, adjust the 200 to some other milliseconds if desired
var _timer = setInterval("imgloaded()",200); 

function imgloaded() {
  // assume they're all loaded
  var loaded = true;

  // test all images for "complete" property
  for(var i = 0, len = document.images.length; i < len; i++) {
    if(!document.images[i].complete) { loaded = false; break; }
  }

  // if loaded is still true, change the HTML
  if(loaded) {
    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "Done.";

    // clear the timer
    clearInterval(_timer);
  }
};
```

Of course, this assumes you have some DIV thrown in somewhere:

```
<div id="msg">Loading...</div>
```

Comment: what if i want to do this for all the elements on the page and not just images?

Comment: thanks Jeff, but intervals are not the best solution, I hope it must stand on something like "$(document).ready" on jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Just add a static `<div>` to the page, informing user that the page is loading. Then add `window.onload` handler and remove the div.

BTW, what’s the reason of this? Don’t users already have page load indicators in their browsers?

Answer (score 0):

You should do async ajax requests for the images and add a call back when it's finished.
Here's some code to illustrate it:

```
var R = new XMLHttpRequest();
R.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (R.readyState == 4) {
    // Do something with R.responseXML/Text ...
    stopWaiting();
  }
};
```

Comment: He doesn't need ajax requests. Anyway, callback would show only that request is finished, but not that image is loaded. You need observe image onload event.

Comment: @Pawka: Won't the request be finished when the image is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you could have an onload event on every image object that runs a function that checks if all images is loaded. This way you don´t need a setTimeOut(). This would however fail if an image didn´t load so you would have to take onerror into account also.